# Query Marklogic processor Nifi

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi, marklogic-9

I recently downloaded MarkLogic nars and I don't see the `URIs query` property on the processor anymore.

How do I specify my search criteria for the list of URI's to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

Ravi,

We dropped the “URIs query” property since the implementation was not as secure as we would like it to be. At this time, QueryMarkLogic allows a set of collections to be specified and documents from those collections will be fetched.

We have discussed other ways of querying uris, but, each of the proposals has some usability issues. If you can log an issue in https://github.com/marklogic/nifi-nars with the name of the customer impacted and a description of the use case, it would help us prioritize this issue.

Thanks.